# How to force 3 decimal places containing zeros at the end of a float in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, format, decimal

I have a very long number in string format like this:

```
$startdate = "1437925621000";
```

It's actually a unix timestamp but when I convert it from a date object to a unix timestamp, it becomes a string.

I need to turn it into this: 1437925621.000 so I wrote a little code that adds a decimal point to the string in the correct position.  It is still a string at this point.

It needs to be a float, though, for comparison so I converted it to a float like this:

```
$startdate = floatval($startdate);
```

But when I convert it to a float, it chops off the three zeros after the decimal point and I need those to be there.

I also tried using number_format but that returns a string and when I convert it back to float the decimal points get chopped off again.  Is there any way around this?

I don't need to print this number.  I need to compare unix timestamps.  I am querying a database that contains dates stored as decimals with 4 decimal places.  They are used as timestamps but are stored as decimals in a MySQL database.

The number I'm referring to is used in a query to select records from this database based on the date, which is stored as a decimal with 4 decimal places.  If I don't have the decimal point, it doesn't compare correctly.

Comment: odd approach to time-stamps can you explain why you need that conversion to start with ?

Comment: 123,000000000000 = 123. Why do you need those zeres there? The number is still the same.

Comment: .000 is just a human display convention. it's NOT necessary to store those useless extra zeroes internally, so PHP doesn't. you should only worry about them when it comes times to DISPLAY the number.

Comment: I'm using a plugin that stores form submissions in the database with a submit_date in decimal format with 4 decimal places.  It's a unix timestamp.  I need to pull a date from a different database that stores its dates in ISO 8601 format, convert it to a timestamp and use it as a condition in a query to pull records from the first database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add 0.0001 to floatval($startdate) and add 0.0001 to other var to compare them

```
floatval($startdate) + 0.0001 === $otherVar + 0.0001
```